# How can I built a basic graph out of this data?

Tags: r, graph

I'm a beginner to R.

I just imported some data from csv file into R and am trying to make a basic graph around it.

Name    | Marks

A       | 65

B       | 78

C       | 55

D       | 66

i created a variable data <- read.table("input.csv")
But after I imported the data successfully, I'm unable to plot a graph that makes sense.
When I tried plot(data) it just gave the following graph
[image]

It didn't make any sense... I want a very basic graph that makes sense.. with the data I have.. anything a pie or bar or anything will do.. Please HELP!!

Comment: Try using `read.csv` instead of `read.table` and try it again

Comment: You're sure the data got read in correctly? Post the output from `dput(data)` (if you called the data "data").

Comment: @Richard Did so.. but the graph didn't look good.. visually.. only a small line marking instead of bars..

Comment: Try `barplot(data[,2], names.arg = data[,1])`

Comment: @AnandaMahto This is the Output of dput(data)
structure(list(Name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), class = "factor"), Marks = c(65L, 78L, 55L, 66L, 93L
)), .Names = c("Name", "Marks"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Comment: Reading the data does not seem to have been the OP's problem, as is evident from the `dput` they shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably not pass the 'Tufte' test, but might be a step in the right direction:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(cbind(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), c(65, 78, 55, 66)))
names(data) <- c('name', 'marks')
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=marks)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mydf<-structure(list(Name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), Marks = c(65L, 78L, 55L, 66L, 93L )), .Names = c("Name", "Marks"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)) 

barplot(mydf$Marks,names.arg=mydf$Name)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most basic plot can be with 'plot(x,y)' command. It is good for screening most data.

```
plot(ddf$Name,ddf$Marks)
```

[image]